# MySQL JSON_TABLE Multiple Nested Paths

Tags: mysql, sql, json, subquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM
    JSON_TABLE(
    '{"TrackingIds":[-1,-2],"Matrices":[22,23]}' 
    ,"$" COLUMNS(
        NESTED path "$.Matrices[*]" COLUMNS (Matrices INT path '$'),
        NESTED path "$.TrackingIds[*]" COLUMNS (TrackingId INT path '$')
    )) AS  j;
```

Which yields:

```
Matrices    TrackingId
22             \N
23             \N
\N             -1
\N             -2
```

How would I get it produce the below:

```
Matrices    TrackingId
22             -1
23             -2
```

Almost like it is a Key Value lookup.
Thanks,
-Tanner

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. From the [MySQL 8 manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html):

> Sibling nested paths—that is, two or more instances of NESTED [PATH] in the same COLUMNS clause—are processed one after another, one at a time. While one nested path is producing records, columns of any sibling nested path expressions are set to NULL. This means that the total number of records for a single match within a single containing COLUMNS clause is the sum and not the product of all records produced by NESTED [PATH] modifiers.

You need an outer query to group related rows together, or not use `NESTED PATH`s